# How to change "broken icon" in WebView

Tags: android, webview

can I replace default broken icon in Android WebView using `java` code?

```
Default Broken icon:
```

[image: Default Broken icon]

```
to custom Broken icon:
```

[image: My custom Broken icon]

Comment: You mean change the HTML code?

Comment: @joao2fast4u: using android java code. using <img onerror="this.src='xxx'" ... > not helped my case.

Answer (score 0):

According to my best knowledge, there is no direct api in sdk to change that default icon. But it might be possible by injecting `javaScript` functions.